# replacing a column value in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in panda which has values like this

```
    Id   ExternalID  class  Unit    Description
0   XYZ     67709           bara      old values
1   ABC     5121     0204   °C      0 values added
```

and i have csv file which has a mapping of Ids with new Ids which needs to be replaced in above dataframe

My csv file :

```
Id    NewId
XYZ   OSS_XYZ
ABC   POW_ABC_A
```

How can I have my dataframe updated so that I have **Id** column in dataframe replace with NewId columns in my csv file with correct mapping? for example after mapping my dataframe should be like this

```
    Id         ExternalID    class  Unit    Description
0   OSS_XYZ       67709             bara      old values
1   POW_ABC_A     5121        0204  °C      0 values added
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [**replace**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-replace/) method.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv') # read the csv

old = df2['Id'].tolist() # the old IDs you want to replace
new = df2['NewId'].tolist() # the new IDs to replace them with

df['Id'].replace(to_replace=old, value=new, inplace=True) # replace

print(df) # view them
```